# Why I lost inherited type?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I have base class User ant two inherited classe - Employee and ExtEmployee.

```
class User { ... }
class Employee : User { ... }
class ExtEmployee : User { ... }
```

For example two methods - GetUsers() and GetUsers2(). GetUsers() returns all users. GetUsers2() has filter and returns users from currentOrganization.

```
public User[] GetUsers()
{
  Employee[] list1 = GetEmployees();
  ExtEmployee[] list2 = GetExtEmployees(); // empty list

  var list = list1.OfType<User>().Union(list2).ToArray();

  return list;
}

public User[] GetUsers2()
{
  Employee[] list1 = GetEmployees();
  ExtEmployee[] list2 = GetExtEmployees(); // empty list

  var list = list1.OfType<User>().Union(list2).ToArray();

  list = list.Where(u => u.OrganizationId == _currentOrganizationId).ToArray();

  returt list;
}

public void Main()
{
  var employees = GetUsers() as Employee[]; // works fine
  var employees2 = GetUsers2() as Employee[]; // employee2 == null
}
```

I cannot cast result of method GetUsers2() to Employee[] - I get null value. Why?

Comment: In `GetUSers2` method, there's no `return` statement. This can't compile. That said, avoid using the `as` keyword when you are sure of the type. `as` can lead to unobvious error, compared to a classic cast. A classic cast will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the type is not correct, while the `as` will silently continue and crash later.

Comment: Sorry, It was mistake. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I don't belive the code you show will reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is not the actual code and I personally have not tried it.

Comment: Is it right way? GetUsers2().OfType<Employee>().ToList();

Comment: @FireShock "This is not the actual code and I personally have not tried it." SERIOUSLY? Stop bothering the internet with your laziness and press F5.

Answer (score 1):

In your example both lines should equal to `null`. You can not cast `User[]` array to `Employee[]` array. Those are different types.

You can however use `IEnumerable.Cast<T>()` and `IEnumerable.OfType<T>()` methods to perform the conversion:

```
//will remove `ExtEmployee` objects.
var employees2 = GetUsers2().OfType<Employee>().ToArray();
//will throw InvalidCastException on ExtEmployee objects unless you define cast operator
var employees2 = GetUsers2().Cast<Employee>().ToArray();
```